# bash: How to retrieve two lines starting with Cd and Cl from a section following a defined string?

Tags: bash

I have a simulation report made up of thousands of standard sections exactly like this:

```
Time = 4

noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.000981702, Final residual = 4.61883e-11, No Iterations 7
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.00156479, Final residual = 6.19981e-10, No Iterations 7
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.813427, Final residual = 83.3066, No Iterations 100
time step continuity errors : sum local = 1.47819e-07, global = 1.78896e-18, cumulative = 4.34085e-18
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.0410561, Final residual = 1.10415e-12, No Iterations 7
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for kl, Initial residual = 0.000179256, Final residual = 3.03264e-08, No Iterations 6
bounding kl, min: -2.43337e-17 max: 0.0157945 average: 5.966e-05
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for kt, Initial residual = 0.0586136, Final residual = 3.49538e-06, No Iterations 4
bounding kt, min: 0 max: 0.000296502 average: 4.84351e-05
ExecutionTime = 13.22 s  ClockTime = 2 s

forces forces write:
    sum of forces:
        pressure : (-58.2965 -2.81001e-17 -93.1677)
        viscous  : (0.91475 1.49625e-17 -0.144504)
        porous   : (0 0 0)
    sum of moments:
        pressure : (-0.465839 30.0683 0.291483)
        viscous  : (-0.000722522 -0.0253209 -0.00457375)
        porous   : (0 0 0)

forceCoeffs forceCoeffs write:
    Cm    = 1.50215
    Cd    = -2.86909
    Cl    = -4.66561
    Cl(f) = -0.830658
    Cl(r) = -3.83495

Time = 5

noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.00714956, Final residual = 1.87826e-10, No Iterations 7
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0115055, Final residual = 9.65481e-10, No Iterations 7
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.957089, Final residual = 12.1321, No Iterations 100
time step continuity errors : sum local = 7.38606e-08, global = -5.69287e-18, cumulative = -1.35202e-18
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for omega, Initial residual = 0.0260988, Final residual = 3.68372e-11, No Iterations 6
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for kl, Initial residual = 0.000118206, Final residual = 9.28461e-09, No Iterations 6
bounding kl, min: -1.60698e-07 max: 0.0193878 average: 7.74828e-05
noneexPBiCGStab:  Solving for kt, Initial residual = 0.0414096, Final residual = 3.85985e-06, No Iterations 4
bounding kt, min: 0 max: 0.0009156 average: 4.8464e-05
ExecutionTime = 16.52 s  ClockTime = 3 s

forces forces write:
    sum of forces:
        pressure : (-25.9825 -1.81748e-17 -39.0016)
        viscous  : (1.0183 3.13511e-19 0.0527919)
        porous   : (0 0 0)
    sum of moments:
        pressure : (-0.195008 8.3975 0.129912)
        viscous  : (0.00026396 -0.0563941 -0.00509149)
        porous   : (0 0 0)

forceCoeffs forceCoeffs write:
    Cm    = 0.417055
    Cd    = -1.24821
    Cl    = -1.94744
    Cl(f) = -0.556666
    Cl(r) = -1.39078

Time = 6
...
```

There could be 10000 sections starting with Time = x where x is the "section number" if you like.

I want to retrieve/echo the lines starting with Cd and Cl from a defined sections.

Example:

I want the lines starting with Cd and Cl from the section beginning with Time = 5, the output should be:

```
Time = 5
    Cd    = -1.24821
    Cl    = -1.94744
```

How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried yet, how farther have you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

For this job is better to use an advanced tool like awk.

With gnu awk you can do something like this:

```
$ sect=5;awk "/^Time/{p=0};/^Time = $sect/{print;p=1};p && (/\sCd/||/^\s+Cl\s+/)" <(echo "$f1")
Time = 5
    Cd    = -1.24821
    Cl    = -1.94744
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **awk**:
If string "Time = 5" is found, set t=1 and print the consecutive strings containing "Cd " and "Cl " while incrementing `i`. Once `i` reaches 2 (i.e string for "Cl " has been printed) EXIT (for better performance).

```
awk '$0~/Time = 5/{print $0; t=1;i=0} t==1 && ($0~/Cd / || $0~/Cl /){print $0; if(++i==2){exit}}' file
```

Output:

```
Time = 5
    Cd    = -1.24821
    Cl    = -1.94744
```

**Note:** If you have multiple possibilities for sections where "Time = 5" you can modify the awk as follows : 
i.e instead of EXIT, set i=0 and t=0 for further iterations

```
awk '$0~/Time = 5/{print $0; t=1;i=0} t==1 && ($0~/Cd / || $0~/Cl /){print $0; if(++i==2){i=0; t=0}}' file
```

You can use **grep** too:

```
 grep -E "Time = 5|Cd | Cl " l1 | grep "Time = 5" -A2 file
```

Output for both these would be :

```
Time = 5
    Cd    = -1.24821
    Cl    = -1.94744
Time = 5
    Cd    = -1.50000
    Cl    = -1.60000
```